# Is there any embedded database/files backup framework for Java?

Tags: java, backup, database-backups

I'm trying to find a Java library/framework, which I can add to my WAR and enable regular backup of files and databases (started on my own timer). I don't want to use a standalone solution for backup (located/maintained apart from my WAR), mostly because it's bigger maintenance headache.

Do you know any such libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Possible but which database are you using? If you are using JavaDb or Apache Derby you already have all the tools you need. You can make a JDBC call to make backups. Here is the code:

```
String sqlstmt = "CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE(?)";
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sqlstmt); 
cs.setString(1,"D:/dbbackups/");
cs.execute(); 
cs.close();
```

And for scheduling the backup tasks you can make use of [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). It is free, opensource and a good job scheduler. If you use some other DB you can still call the command using the System.exec method from the scheduler task.

Comment: Making a copy of local data is just 10% of backup job. Normally a backup process also includes "rolling" backup archives, transferring them to other servers, making Amazon S3/EBS copies, etc..

Comment: @Vincenzo , I don't think there is a framework to automate the entire process